# template error ENOENT: no such file or directory when running ionic serve -l

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, angular5

I merged my Angular 5 project into Ionic 3 framework and also updated the compiler.json. After that, I ran the command `npm install` to created node_modules. But, after running the command `ionic serve -l`, I see the following error:

> template error, "/var/www/html/githubIonic/dist/out-tsc/src/app/app.component.html": Error: ENOENT: no such 
>               file or directory, open '/var/www/html/githubIonic/dist/out-tsc/src/app/app.component.html'

have I missed anything?

Below is my ionic info:

```html
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v9.11.1
    npm  : 6.2.0 
    OS   : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Here is the package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "githubIonic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main":"main.ts",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.2.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.9.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` ?

Comment: @DavidR posted, check above.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to install `ionic` globally then followed up `app-scripts` install. Use below commands,

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@latest
sudo npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: The first command ran well. When running the second command, I see the following: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/niladri/node_modules/node-sass/build'    Build failed with error code: 1  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/niladri/package.json'   Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Also, after running ionic serve -l, gives the same error as stated in the question.

Comment: For EACCES Error, You need to follow these => https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions